# Cannot acquire a managed connection from the run-time connection manager

Tags: sql-server, ssis, odata

I need to extract data from C4C and I use SSIS and Odata connector to do the job. It worked fine for a couple of month but now my SSIS job is not working any more since 2 days and I cannot find any tips on the web. I tried the registry key, update my VS to 2017 but nothing worked! I'm sure it's related to TSL1.2 but don't know how to fix it. In development tools, I can see data in preview mode but when I execute the job it gives me an error:

> Cannot acquire a managed connection from the run-time connection manager

Comment: Christine, were you able to fix this? Having the same issue when moving the SSIS job from a 2016 server to a 2017 server.